# C# restarting Threading.Timer with Change does not stop initial Timer instance

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Good day.

My question is a follow-up (of sorts) to this post: [Resetting Threading Timer if it's called a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109166/resetting-threading-timer-if-its-called-a-second-time)

I've tried the suggestions there, and it partially solved my problem.

I have a C# application that contains four Threading.Timers. this is how I designed them:

Summary: two threads run every 2 hours, one thread runs only once, one thread runs every minute. All four threads post updates to a ListBox (lstMonitor). I also have a button that clears lstMonitor, and should restart all four Threads.

```
public partial class FullSynchro : Form
{
    public System.Threading.Timer TimerReference;
    public bool TimerCanceled;

    readonly TimeSpan tsTwo = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);

    TimeSpan tickTwo = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan tickOne = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);

    readonly TimeSpan tsFour = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    TimeSpan tickFour = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

    System.Threading.Timer thSyncTwo, thSyncOne, thSyncThree, thSyncFour;

    public delegate void InvokeDelegate(string input);

    FullSynchro objOne, objTwo, objThree, objFour;
    TimerCallback tcbOne, tcbTwo, tcbThree, tcbFour;

    public FullSynchro()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FullSynchro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* instantiating the class that gets called by the Timer. */
        objOne = new FullSynchro();
        tcbOne = new TimerCallback(PerformSyncOne);

        /* instantiate the Timer object */
        thSyncOne = new System.Threading.Timer(tcbOne, objOne, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
        objOne.TimerReference = thSyncOne;

        objTwo = new FullSynchro();
        tcbTwo = new TimerCallback(PerformSyncTwo);
        thSyncTwo = new System.Threading.Timer(tcbTwo, objTwo, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
        objTwo.TimerReference = thSyncTwo;

        /* one-time Sync */
        objThree = new FullSynchro();
        tcbThree = new TimerCallback(PerformSyncThree);
        thSyncThree = new System.Threading.Timer(tcbThree, objThree, 0, 0);
        objThree.TimerReference = thSyncThree;

        objFour = new FullSynchro();
        tcbFour = new TimerCallback(PerformSyncFour);
        thSyncFour = new System.Threading.Timer(tcbFour, objFour, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
        objFour.TimerReference = thSyncFour;
    }

        void PerformSyncOne(object StateObj)
        {
            //code goes here
        }

        void PerformSyncTwo(object StateObj)
        {
            //code goes here
        }

        void PerformSyncThree(object StateObj)
        {
            //code goes here
        }

        void PerformSyncFour(object StateObj)
        {
            //code goes here
        }

    private void btnOverride_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Message.Show("Are you sure you wish to restart Sync?", this.Text) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            thSyncTwo.Change(0, 0);

            //lstMonitor.Items.Clear();
            //PerformSync();
        }
    }
}
```

The button code kinda worked; `thSyncTwo.Change()` did execute `PerformSyncTwo()` from the start, but the first instance of `PerformSyncTwo()` still kept on posting updates to lstMonitor.

I've read about using `WaitHandle`, but I can't make it work. I tried using `Dispose()` on almost everything thread-related in my code, but the first instance of the Timer still kept on running. I really need to "kill" the previous instances of those Timers, then "resurrect" them.

So, is it possible? Or should I use a different kind of Timer?

Comment: Im slightly confused - you have a form FullSynchro, then it the load of that form, you create 4 more copies of the form, which should each in turn make 4 more copies, etc..

Comment: Instead of using 4 timers you could use just a single (usually in a form of quanted? working thread) and dividers, multithreading is more complicated by definition. This way you don't need synchronization objects, but a normal state objects (which are altered in same thread).

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah, I don't remember why I designed it that way; this application is over four years old, and is working normally. The button to restart the threads is a new enhancement requested by our client. I'll see if I can remove them and keep the app working normally.

Comment: @Sinatr Each thread is required to run simultaneously, so I can't merge them into one thread

Comment: Im guessing that your timers arent truly resetting because there are many instances and you reset 1 but not all the others.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to stop timer you can use
`timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)`
It's works and stops timer without disposing. After that you should invoke `.Change()` with proper values to start the timer again.

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't work; the first instance of the threads still kept running.